# java.io.FileNotFoundException error after adding in if statement

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, filenotfoundexception

I am developing a Hangman code for class & I am supposed to have three different levels of difficulties compiled of 20 different possible words/phrases to guess from. I have the three text documents contained in the same folder as my program, but for some reason I keep getting

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
at FinalProject.showfile(FinalProject.java:137)
at FinalProject.game(FinalProject.java:48)
at FinalProject.main(FinalProject.java:35)
```

I don't know what to do to correct this. I am new to coding and don't have a great understanding towards this.
I've included the part of the code for which allows the user to select the level of their desire & the code which finds a random word from each file. If more is required, I can give the whole thing.

I've looked at many other threads regarding this same problem but my issue appears to differ from them all. Prior to me adding in the if statement with all the other levels, I simply had:

```
fileName = "lv1text.txt";
```

and that worked just fine. But now that I have included the if statement, this error has come up.

I have tried using the exact directory but that still gives the same error.

```
    private static int levelSelect (int levelSelection) throws IOException
{
    levelSelection = 0;
    System.out.println("What level of difficulty would you like to play?");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for Easy\nEnter 2 for Medium\nEnter 3 for Hard");
    levelSelection = getInt("",1,3);
    return levelSelection;
}

private static String showfile(String fileName) throws IOException
{
    levelSelect(levelSelection);
    if (levelSelection == 1)
    {
        fileName = "lv1list.txt";
    }
    else if (levelSelection == 2)
    {
        fileName = "lv2list.txt";
    }
    else if (levelSelection == 3)
    {
        fileName = "lv3list.txt";
    } 
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner (new File (fileName));
    int i = 0; 
    String[] impWord = new String[20];
    while (inFile.hasNextLine())
    {
        impWord[i] = inFile.nextLine();
        i++;
    }
    inFile.close();
    int rNum = ((int)Math.floor((impWord.length-1)*Math.random()-1));
    fWord = impWord[rNum];
    return fWord;
}
```

Comment: try with complete path

Comment: I've tried that, still does the same thing.

Comment: Before I added in the if statement with the other levels, I simply had fileName = "lv1list.txt"; and it worked

Comment: show how you specified complete path

Comment: "C:\\Users\\Elijah\\Desktop\\CHANG, E-FinalProject\\lv1list.txt"

Comment: why is tha `,` between? may be check this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html

Comment: that's the name of the folder

Comment: but that shouldn't be the issue as prior to adding the if statement, doing the same method worked perfectly fine. so I feel like something has to be added or changed in regards to that

Comment: Does the file open with a text editor? Can you edit it manually?

Comment: Yes I can edit it in notepad

Comment: Your `levelSelect()` method doesn't work - you pass in a `levelSelection` parameter, manipulate that parameter and return the value of the parameter - but your `showFile()` method works with a `levelSelection` field. This field is never updated in your shown code, it therefore probably stays at `0`. That means that none of your `if` conditions are true, so the `fileName` probably also stays empty...

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I figured it out. Appreciate your help